# Android - Adding functions dynamically in a hash map from Application and Jar

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, jar, hashmap

Hi I have wrapper application and a jar which runs in a service of wrapper app. In the complete solution the Jar is my product which I can't revile to users, but I need to give them the liberty to extend the functionality by registering function against a command received from socket. They can do it in the wrapper application. I already have some commands coming from flex UI and they are processed like following:

```
    private void processCommand(String tempCommand) throws NumberFormatException, IOException, ELearningException 
{
    ApplicationLog.log("Command Queue " + tempCommand, true);

    String[] commandParameters = tempCommand.split("#");

    switch (Integer.parseInt(commandParameters[0])) 
    {
        case CONSTANTS.INITIALIZE:
            if (this.m_isInitialized)
                break;
            else
            {
                InitializeTeacherJar.instantiate(tempCommand.split("#")[1], this.baseContext, tempCommand.split("#")[2]);

                parent = InitializeTeacherJar.getInstance();

                parent.setMyFlexServer(this.m_localServerSocket);
                parent.setMyFlexSocket(this.m_localSocket);

                this.m_isInitialized = true;
            }
            break;
        case CONSTANTS.LOGIN:

            /**
             * Store student details in hash map
             */

            this.writeToStudentJava(tempCommand, JavaServerThreadForTeacher.getIpAddress().getHostAddress());

            if(tempCommand.split("#")[1].equalsIgnoreCase(CONSTANTS.SUCCESS))
            {
                HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> temp = parent.getStudentIPList();
                ArrayList<String> value= new ArrayList<String>();
                value.add(tempCommand.split("#")[3]);
                value.add("present");
                temp.put(tempCommand.split("#")[2], value);
                parent.setStudentIPList(temp);

                if (StudentUtility.studentCounter < 0)
                    StudentUtility.studentCounter = 0;

                StudentUtility.studentCounter = StudentUtility.studentCounter + 1;

                parent.getMyFlexSocket().getOutputStream().write((CONSTANTS.PING + parent.getDelimiter() + StudentUtility.studentCounter).getBytes());

                System.out.print("StudentUtility.studentCounter :: "+StudentUtility.studentCounter);
            }
            break;
        case CONSTANTS.COURSE:
            parent.setCourse(tempCommand.split(parent.getDelimiter())[1]);
            break;
        case CONSTANTS.ACTION:
            parent.performAction(tempCommand, commandParameters[3]);

            parent.getMyFlexSocket().getOutputStream().write((CONSTANTS.PING + parent.getDelimiter() + StudentUtility.studentCounter).getBytes());
            break;

        case CONSTANTS.INTERACTIVE:
            if (commandParameters[1].equalsIgnoreCase(CONSTANTS.Play)) {
                parent.playAudio(commandParameters[2], true);
            } else if (commandParameters[1].equalsIgnoreCase(CONSTANTS.Record)) {
                parent.startAudioRecording(commandParameters[2], true);
            } else {
                parent.playAudio(commandParameters[2], false);
            }

        case CONSTANTS.TTL:
            this.m_isWifiConnected();
            break;
        case CONSTANTS.DELETE:
            parent.deleteFile(commandParameters[1], true);
            // deleteRecording(commandParameters[3],
            // commandParameters[1]
            // + commandParameters[2]);
            // deleteEveryThing(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            // .getAbsolutePath() + "/" + commandParameters[2]);
            // deleteEveryThing(pathToSave + "/Response/" + course + "/"
            // + commandParameters[1]);
            break;
        case CONSTANTS.RESTART:
            StudentUtility.sendToEveryStudent(tempCommand);
            StudentUtility.displayOnProjector(tempCommand);
            parent.setStudentIPList(new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>());
            parent.setCourse("");
            break;
        case CONSTANTS.EXIT:
            StudentUtility.displayOnProjector(tempCommand);
            StudentUtility.sendToEveryStudent(tempCommand);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

This is inside my Jar and I want users to be able to add any number of cases as functions in  wrapper application. More over, preferably, I would like to put the existing cases in the same hash map used for registering commands and functions in wrapper application.

I need to know the correct design pattern and some advice how to go about it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine design pattern Command with a mapping of function code to commands. This has the benefit of moving the implementations to their own self-contained classes, which makes code more manageable and easier to test.

You might want to use Design Pattern Visitor instead of modifying the command map, but depends on your circumstances.

A common Interface for your commands

```
public Interface Command {
 void action();
}
```

Create a bunch of concrete commands

```
public class Course implements Command {
  private final String tempCommand;
  private final ParentClass parent;

  public Course(final String tempCommand, final ParentClass parent) {
    this.tempCommand = tempCommand;
    this.parent = parent;
  }

  public void action() {
    parent.setCourse(tempCommand.split(parent.getDelimiter())[1]);
  }
};
```

Map the preexisting function codes to commands.

```
  private final Map<Integer, Command> getBuiltIns() {
      Private final Map<Integer, Command> cmdMap = new HashMap<Integer, Command>();
      cmdMap.add(CONSTANTS.COURSE, new Command(tempCommand, parent));
      <etc>
     return cmdMap;
  }

  private final cmdMap = getBuildIns();
```

Make a method that can add commands

```
public void addCommand(final int code, final Command command) {
  // Check if code is already used, or there might be trouble
  cmdMap.add(code, command);
}
```

Find the command then execute.

```
private void processCommand(String tempCommand) throws NumberFormatException, IOException, ELearningException 
{
  final Command theCommand = cmdMap.get(Integer.parseInt(commandParameters[0]));
  theCommand.action();
}
```